# How to convert point cloud .pts file into .pcd file format?

Tags: point-clouds

I downloaded big point cloud file with extension .pts and I want to convert it into .pcd format. What is the simplest and easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is .pts ASCII?

If so, you can easily write a parser for it and save it as a .pcd.

Or, if you are looking for a tool, [meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) can read in plain XYZ data and save it to .ply format (remove all header content, if there is any). .ply files are supported by the Point Cloud Library, you can either convert it or just read in the .ply.